# Assert Variable is not Null

Tags: c#, kotlin

I have a Variable with type `DateTime?`

In a Function I check it for being `null` and want to use it afterwards without always having to `?.` every call. In e.g. Kotlin the IDE recognizes a check like that and asserts that the variable cannot be `null` afterwards. Is there a way to do this in C#?

```
DateTime? BFreigabe = getDateTime();
if (BFreigabe == null) return false;
TimeSpan span = BFreigabe - DateTime.Now; 
//Shows Error because it.BFreigabe has the type DateTime?, even though it can't be null
```

**Edit:**

When using

```
TimeSpan span = BFreigabe.Value - DateTime.Now;
```

instead it works **in this case** because `.Value` doesn't have nullsafety at all. However, considering that this would compile even without the null check and just produce an error, the general question still remains. How can one persuade C# that a former nullable variable isn't nullable any more?

**Edit 2**

Casting DateTime on the Variable works.

```
TimeSpan span = (DateTime)BFreigabe - DateTime.Now;
```

Still not as safe as in Kotlin, but similar enough.

Comment: Replace `TimeSpan span = BFreigabe - DateTime.Now;`  with `TimeSpan span = BFreigabe.Value - DateTime.Now;`

Comment: `BFreigabe.Value - DateTime.Now` or `BFreigabe.GetValueOrDefault() - DateTime.Now`

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of your first **Edit** you have checking for `null` before this code so anyway it will not be null, but you are working incorrect with `nullable` type when you write `BFreigabe - DateTime.Now`. So there is nothing connected with nullsafety

Comment: @Samvel Petrosov in Kotlin when you nullcheck a variable like that it will not throw an error when doing actions requiring null safety because the compiler recognizes that the variable cannot be `null` any more, meaning the nullable type is automatically casted to a non-nullable type

Comment: @Looki you problem is not with `DateTime?` in this case. You problem is that the result of  `BFreigabe - DateTime.Now` is `TimeSpan?`. So when you cast `DateTime?` to `DateTime` or taking the `Value` the result becomes `TimeSpan`. So you can do even this `TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan)(BFreigabe - DateTime.Now);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the previous check, you can access the value. Nullable types always have two properties: `HasValue` and `Value`.

You could either cast to `DateTime` (Without the `?`) or use the value property.

```
DateTime? BFreigabe = getDateTime();
if (!BFreigabe.HasValue == null) 
    return false;

TimeSpan span = BFreigabe.Value - DateTime.Now;
```

Or store the nullable variable in a non nullable variable:

```
DateTime? BFreigabe = getDateTime();
if (BFreigabe.HasValue == null) 
{
    DateTime neverNull = BFreigabe.Value;
    TimeSpan span = neverNull  - DateTime.Now;
}
```

This will get full editor support and guarantee that there is no `NullReferenceExcpetion`.

**EDIT**: Because your question states **Assert**.  Assert usually means that we will throw an exception if the state is invalid.

In this case, omit the check for nullness. If you access `var.Value` while `var` is null, this will throw a `NullReferenceException`. This moves the responsibility to the caller.

Another option would be to not use the nullable variable. Either by converting it (see the second listing) or by not accepting Nullable types as a parameter.

```
function TimeSpan Calc(DateTime time)
{
    // here we know for sure, that time is never null
}
```

Comment: I've solved the problem by casting `DateTime` to the Variable

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DateTime? BFreigabe = getDateTime();
if (!BFreigabe.HasValue) return false;
DateTime BFreigabeValue = BFreigabe.Value;
TimeSpan span = BFreigabeValue - DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to convert NULL value to any value, that is irrelevant.

```
DateTime? BFreigabe = getDateTime();
if (BFreigabe == null) return false;
TimeSpan span = (BFreigabe??DateTime.Now) - DateTime.Now;
```